# How to launch Android Studio in elementary OS

Tags: release-freya, development, android, ide, android-studio

I am using freya. I have installed Android Studio. I don't find it in application menu. Every time I have to use `studio.sh` manually.

How can I launch it directly from app menu and from terminal ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**To launch from Applications menu**

*Option 1*:

- First Open Android Studio
- Select "Configure"

  [image: Imgur]
- Click on "Create Desktop Entry"

  [image: Imgur]

Now you can launch it from applications menu.

---

*Option 2*:

Creating `.desktop` file.

Open terminal and run:

```
nano /usr/share/applications/jetbrains-studio.desktop
```

Copy paste the following lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Android Studio
Icon=/path/to/android-studio/bin/studio.png
Exec="/path/to/android-studio/bin/studio.sh" %f
Comment=Develop with pleasure!
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-studio
```

**Note**: Replace `/path/to` with exact path.

---

**To launch from terminal**:

You have to just create a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). Create it in `/usr/local/bin`. All you need is to run the command:

The general syntax is:

```
sudo ln -s /full/path/to/your/file /usr/local/bin/name_of_new_command
```

The command: (After replacing correct path)

```
sudo ln -s ~/android-studio/bin/studio.sh /usr/local/bin/studio
```

Now open terminal and run `studio` to launch.

Answer (score -2):

For starting it in Terminal, you can use the path to Android-studio's launcher
filesystem: .../usr/local/android-studio/bin/studio.sh