# Problem with double icons in Plank dock

Tags: plank

have a strange problem with the dock.   I have installed Android Studio, and used "Create Desktop Entry", which added it to the Applications menu, I then dragged this onto the Dock.

When the application is closed, it's fine, it shows a single entry, but when I open Android Studio, it then have two dock icons, as if the launcher and the open application are treated as separate items.

No other applications do this.

I have deleted the plan config file and recreated, and it's done the same.

How can I fix this annoyance?

Thanks.

Comment: See [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/18/one-of-my-apps-has-a-second-fuzzy-icon-in-plank-how-can-i-workaround-this) answer for help with this. Basically you will need to add a `StartupWMClass` line to your .desktop file. Based on [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3829/how-to-launch-android-studio-in-elementary-os) answer I presume `StartupWMClass=jetbrains-studio` will do the trick.

Comment: Good to hear! Would you mind posting what you used as an answer for the next person?